# release lock on log file log4j after process is completed

Tags: log4j, log4j2, slf4j

I am using lsf4j on top of log4j to log events in my app. I have a custom file appender that is being used to log events to multipule log files, a main log file and log file for each process instance my app manages. 
I also have a scheduled purge task that runs in parallel and its purpose is to clear all log files of completed processes but when trying to delete those files the following ERROR is thrown: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".
If I restart my app those files do get purged when the purge task runs, hence the reason is that the lock set by log4j is released only upon restart.
I need a way to programmatically lift the lock on a log file given it`s name.

Comment: I think lsf4j is misspelled, it should be slf4j.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that appenders of concluded processes were not removed and thus the log files for those processes remained locked and were freed only upon restart of the entire application. My solution was removing the corresponding appender upon completion of the process.

```
Configuration conf = ((LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).getConfiguration();
RoutingAppender app = (RoutingAppender) conf.getAppender("dynamic appender name");
app.deleteAppender("appender responsible for the completed process");
```